# Laravel 5.3 - Sharing $user variable to all views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So after finding out that sharing views in Controller.php's constructer no longer works because it always returns `null` to `Auth::user()`, I am looking for a different way to do it.

I am simply looking for a way to pass a `$user` variable with the current signed in user to all my views.

Previous way which worked in 5.2 and below:

```
public function __construct()
{
    view()->share('signed_in', Auth::check());
    view()->share('user', Auth::user());
 }
```

This no longer works. How else can I share variables?

I have tried:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->signed_in = Auth::guest();

        view()->share('signed_in', $this->signed_in);
        view()->share('user', $this->user);

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

But the code above does not work. It does load the page without a "Undefined Variable $user" error but it just show the navigation bar and then nothing else. It also messes up the site CSS for some reason.

Is there any other way I can do it? 
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The Auth::user() and Auth::check() function is available in views by default, is there a specific reason you would still want to use `$user` instead?

Comment: Well the main reason is that I am trying to upgrade my large application from 5.2 to 5.3 and it is already using `$user` to access the current user to make it easy to read and write. It's also easier doing `$user->can('doSomething')` than to do `Auth::user()->can('doSomthing'`.

Comment: perhaps this answer can be helpful to you: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/viewshare-not-working-in-51/replies/90831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue quite easily.

In my `\App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php`

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    private $user;
    private $signed_in;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            $this->signed_in = Auth::check();

            view()->share('signed_in', $this->signed_in);
            view()->share('user', $this->user);

            return $next($request);
        });

    }

}
```

By putting the `view()->share()` in a closure of a middleware, I was able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example, you could create a new service provider, and register it in your `config/app.php`, and put the share logic in there.

Let's start with creating a new service provider:

```
~/path/to/project$  php artisan make:provider ShareWithViewServiceProvider
```

You should see the message `Provider created successfully.`

Then you should edit your `config/app.php`, and add the new service provider you've just created:

```
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */

App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\ShareWithViewServiceProvider::class, // <-- This is the new entry
```

Then create your logic in the boot method of your service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ShareWithViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share([
            'user' => auth()->user(),
            'signedIn' => auth()->check(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that `auth()->user()` will return `null` if you are not signed in.

As a shorter solution, you can just put the share logic in the `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`, which Laravel creates by default, and has nothing in it (it's there for us to use).

Comment: This does not work because `auth()->user()` returns null on a Service Provider even if the user is signed in because session has not be initialized yet.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Then put it in a middleware, and make sure to include this new middleware after the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` middleware has been initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Using the middleware callback the way you do is a correct way to go about this, but your assignment is wrong.

Use this instead:

```php
$this->signed_in = Auth::check();
```